# While trying to insert a layer to an existing .mxd, I get an AssertionError, and can't figure out why

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, assertionerror

I am trying to add new raster layers to an existing .mxd (and then eventually remove the old ones, once I've updated the new raster layer's symbology to match the old ones). I'm running into an issue where the InsertLayer line is returning this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\bpaladino2\Documents\GRACE_Forecast_Test\AddToMxd.py", line
> 24, in 
> arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, ref_layer, new_layer)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\ArcPy\arcpy\utils.py", line
> 182, in fn_
> return fn(*args, **kw)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\ArcPy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1432, in
> InsertLayer
> assert isinstance(insert_layer, Layer) AssertionError

Here is the code I am working with (so far):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\bpaladino2\\Documents\\GRACE\\ForecastTest\\output\\archive\\TEST"

path = "C:\\Users\\bpaladino2\\Documents\\GRACE\\ForecastTest\\output\\archive\\TEST\\" #Path to Raster

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\\Users\\bpaladino2\\Documents\\GRACE\\ForecastTest\\GRACE_FO_GWS.mxd") 

raster_list = arcpy.ListDatasets("*","Raster")

##for line in raster_list:
    #print line

raster = raster_list[0]

##print raster

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
new_raster = arcpy.management.MakeRasterLayer(raster, "GWS_30D.tif")
new_layer = arcpy.management.SaveToLayerFile(new_raster, "GWS_30D.lyr")
ref_layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(df)[2]
arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, ref_layer, new_layer)


#print ref_layer
```

Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

You might check that new_layer or ref_layer are indeed raster layers.

Or this might work.

```
new_raster = arcpy.management.MakeRasterLayer(raster, "GWS_30D.tif").getOutput(0)
new_layer = arcpy.management.SaveToLayerFile(new_raster, "GWS_30D.lyr")
ref_layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(df)[2]
arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, ref_layer, new_raster)
```